# merge two dataframe in one (df) with external left join (on df1) AND no match for the rigth (on df2)

Tags: r

I have two dataframes : `df1` with 62,107 lines and 68 columns and `df2` with 98,323 lines and 68 columns, same structure.

A want ALL the lines from `df1` and ONLY the non_matching lines of `df2` (on a column names "PK") ; into a final dataframe, df.

I've been looking around for outer join WITH ADDING a non matching request, but did not find any combined syntax.

I finally tried things like that :

```
df <- (merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("PK"), by.y = -c("PK")))
```

did not work !

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with expected output

Comment: Can you explain the structure a bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use sqldf for this, below you will return all rows that do not exist in df2.

```
df <- sqldf("Select * from df1 LEFT JOIN df2 on df1.ID = df2.ID
      WHERE df2.ID IS NULL")
```

"A want ALL the lines from df1 and ONLY the non_matching lines of df2 (on a column names "PK") ; into a final dataframe, df." Do essentially accomplish this you would just perform a left join without the null clause.

Comment: This exclude the entries from df1 matching in df2... Not what I understand from OP sentence, but it's so badly written I can be wrong...

Comment: yeah, hard to say what this person is exactly after. Really the only way to keep all rows from the original dataframe is to use a left a join but then it will return matches and non matches.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I finally did.

Comment: The problem is over ! Thanks everybody.